# Imported short clip with obscenely high framecount

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, movie-clip-editor

So I'm quite new to Blender, and I'm running into many problems importing my video.

When I first try to import it, I get the 2 channels for video and audio, which is expected, but the video channel has a framecount of 38562221 when the audio has 12859 (7:08 video at 30fps).

I have no idea what to do, and when I render the video nothing appears at all except the very first frame for 1/30 of a second. After this it's completely blank with the checkerboard pattern.

I'm so confused. Is there something Blender has against WMV files? I tried again with an MP4 also and it did the ridiculous framecount (note for both of these videos under properties it was specified to be at 30fps). So I'm completely stuck. Help!

[image: Ridiculous framerate]
[image: more settings]

Hopefully this is something simple i missed.

Comment: Handbrake is free and can quickly clean up stuff like this before you import into Blender. It is great to use to set the frame rate to something better (e.g., 30 or 60) and consistent across the clip.

Answer (score 2):

There is a hard coded frame count in Blender. You *could* recompile it with a larger frame count and see if things work, as I believe your piece is over the maximum. While I cannot remember the number, you shouldn't have too much trouble locating it.

It might be more optimal to chop the piece into smaller portions using another tool and reassemble them.

Comment: afaik the hard coded frame range is limited to 300,000. So this shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Last time I looked 38562221 is larger than 300000. :)

Comment: yep, I think so as well... It must be a bug or a decoding problem with ffmpeg. A bit over 7 minutes can't be so much frames with 30fps.

Comment: It is likely a misinterpretation of the frame rate numerator and denominator, or one of the codecs that use different methods. Any number of things could be wrong. Bottom line is that the VSE is a poor tool to be using in this instance.